# not able to use delete query for multiple and condition

Tags: sql

i need to use 3 and condition  in an sql delete statement but i am not able to execute it.
how is the below possible?

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("delete form loadcase1 where (projectname='ABC' **and** phase='123e') **and** (impact='impact' **and** loadcase='loadc')"); 

$sth->execute() or die "$!";
```

how do i execute this condition .

Comment: `i am not able to execute it`: what does it mean exactly? is there any error?

Comment: yes it gives a error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where projectname='ARIA' and phase='MULE_A' OR impact='FRONT_IMPACT' and loadcas' at line 1 at (eval 28) line 23

Comment: Then edit your question and add the error so we can try to help you solve the problem. Nobody will understand what's wrong if you just say `i am not able to execute it`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use this for 2 conditions, with OR

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("delete form loadcase1 where (projectname='ABC' and phase='123e') OR (impact='impact' and loadcase='loadc')");
```

so it will delete (projectname='ABC' and phase='123e') and (impact='impact' and loadcase='loadc') conditions together. I cant see any 3. condition in your question

Comment: i have highlighted the and

Comment: there are 2 condition in your question 
1-) (projectname='ABC' **and** phase='123e') 
2-)(impact='impact' **and** loadcase='loadc')

what do you want to want to achieve with this query?

Comment: i need to delete a record based on these 2 conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you need to use the words `And` and `Or` instead of `&&` and `||`.